# Sphinx 2.2.11 - Infix search not working consistently for some terms

Tags: sphinx

I am using Sphinx 2.2.11 with min_infix_len set to 3. For some terms, however, I get a really
strange behavior. For example: while **flor*** or **nat*** yields no results, **floru*** or **nata*** suddenly do. Shouldn't the results that appear for **floru*** also appear for **flor***? And, likewise, the results that appear for **nata*** also appear for **nat***?

My index settings look like this:

```
dict = keywords
min_word_len = 1
min_infix_len = 3
infix_fields = description
index_exact_words = 1

blend_chars = U+23, U+26, U+2B, U+2D, U+2E, U+2F, U+2C->U+2E
blend_mode = trim_none, trim_head, trim_tail, trim_both, skip_pure
html_strip = 1

charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z
```

Is there something wrong with my index settings, a known bug or anything? Any help is much appreciated.